# How do you run Multiple XMLA Alter Commands at the same time?

Tags: ssas, ssms

I have the following two XMLA alter commands that individually work fine.  I would like to run them at the same time in SQL Management studio.  I have tried wrapping them in command, batch, and a number of other elements.  I can't seem to get anything to work correctly.

```
<Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Object>
        <DatabaseID>DB1</DatabaseID>
        <RoleID>Role</RoleID>
    </Object>
    <ObjectDefinition>
        <Role xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400">
            <ID>Role</ID>
            <Name>ReadersRole</Name>
            <Members>
                <Member>
                    <Name>Domain\ReaderUserName</Name>
                </Member>
            </Members>
        </Role>
    </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>


<Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ObjectProperties" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Object>
        <DatabaseID>DB2</DatabaseID>
        <RoleID>Role</RoleID>
    </Object>
    <ObjectDefinition>
        <Role xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400">
            <ID>Role</ID>
            <Name>ReadersRole</Name>
            <Members>
                <Member>
                    <Name>Domain\ReaderUserName</Name>
                </Member>
            </Members>
        </Role>
    </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try just putting a

`<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine"></Batch>`

tag around them?

Comment: I tried adding Batch around the query and got the following error.

The Batch element at line 7, column 22 (namespace urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis) cannot appear under Envelope/Body/Execute/Command.

All the other wrappers I have tried have given similar errors.

Comment: Oops. The namespace is required. Edited my answer to reflect that.